# When the container of swiper is set to none and then set back to block, the autoplay of swiper no longer works

Tags: swiper.js, autoplay

demo:[codepen](https://codepen.io/rfrkk/pen/wvQQwvq)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<button class="none">change display to none</button>
<button class="block">change display to block</button>
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">PAGE 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">PAGE 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">PAGE 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/10.0.4/swiper-bundle.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>


//script.js
var swiper;
window.onload = function () {
  swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    autoplay: {
      delay: 1500,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
      pauseOnMouseEnter: true
    },
    loop: true,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination"
    }
  });

  $(".block").click(function () {
    $(".swiper").css("display", "block");
  });
  $(".none").click(function () {
    $(".swiper").css("display", "none");
  });
};


//style.css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

The preset of swiper has autopay.
When clicking the "change display to none" button to set the display of container to none and then clicking the "change display to block" button to set back to block. At this moment, **the autoplay of swiper no longer works.**

[swiper api](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api)
I can't find any method in the documentation.
How to fix it ?